# Error thrown by gpg.import_key in saltstack state file

Tags: python, gnupg, salt-stack

I am receiving a weird error in my salt state file, when I'm trying to import a GPG key using this state file.  Interestingly, it appears that the key has been correctly imported into GPG.

```
gpg.import_key_public:
  module.run:
    - name: gpg.import_key
    - user: ubuntu
    - text: |
        {{ salt['pillar.get']('gpg:public_key', '') | indent(8) }}
    - require:
      - pip: python-gnupg
```

I get the following error:

```
          ID: gpg.import_key_public
    Function: module.run
        Name: gpg.import_key
      Result: False
     Comment: Module function gpg.import_key threw an exception. Exception: list indices must be integers, not str
     Started: 01:03:21.103688
    Duration: 10.676 ms
     Changes:
```

Comment: Here's the function... I can't find any reason for this error! Might want to submit it as an issue to the Saltstack github https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/develop/salt/modules/gpg.py#L600

Comment: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/24862